# MySQL trigger inserting every year

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table `holiday(id, year, daysLeft, id_employee)`, every employee have 22 holiday day in a year.

I need a trigger, in first January every, inserting for every employee a line of the new year and 22 as days left.

example for the `employee (id=1) inserting (id, 2015, 22, 1)`.

Thanks so much

Comment: You don't *really* want a trigger, you want either a scheduled task, or a method to calculate the holiday allowance on the fly

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO holiday
SELECT YEAR(NOW()), 22, id_employee
FROM employee
```

Just do an INSERT --- SELECT.

More info  [from MySQL here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Whoops I added the NOW() function. The trigger needs to fire in the new year.